# Can I show a list of contacts within category, on the 'List all contact categories' page in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, foreach, contacts

So in a nutshell, you have two options for displaying Contacts in Joomla:

1. Show all Joomla Contact Categories.
2. Show all Joomla Contacts in a single Category.

I want to use the first option, but merge a list underneath each Category showing the list of contacts within that category, and a link to their profile.

The simplest way I thought of this was to edit a template override of the file com_contact/categories/default_items.php

I found a point where I want the list to appear, and then copied and pasted the code from the Category view (that generates the list of contacts).

```
<ul>
    <?php // Add list of contacts for each category
    foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) : ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContactHelperRoute::getContactRoute($item->slug, $item->catid)); ?>">
            <?php echo $item->name; ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

But I am assuming I can't just copy and paste, as there needs to be an extra node added to $this->items.

At the moment, no list is being generated, just the `<ul>` outside the `foreach` loop.. but also interestingly, the `<li>` and the `<a>` IS being generated.. but linking to the current page I'm on (Probably because `$item->slug` is still being seen as the category).

So can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to reference the contacts within a category? All I'm after is the name and the slug/URL.

UPDATE:
I saw this in the same file (default_items.php) and although I realise it's referring to child categories... would this be a place to start for the actual contacts within the categories?

```
<?php if (count($item->getChildren()) > 0) :?>
    <div class="collapse fade" id="category-<?php echo $item->id;?>">
        <?php
        $this->items[$item->id] = $item->getChildren();
        $this->parent = $item;
        $this->maxLevelcat--;
        echo $this->loadTemplate('items');
        $this->parent = $item->getParent();
        $this->maxLevelcat++;
        ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

BUMP - Does anyone have any experience with this? Or being able to call individual contacts when viewing a category? How are they linked?

Comment: Before you go too far I would go check extensively in the options. I believe that if you look at the sample data also (the testing one or the learn joomla one) you can see some complex ways of setting the view up with many many options.  I know that you can show the items in a specific category in some versions of that layout but it probably requires setting 15 options correctly.

Comment: Which version of Joomla?

Comment: @Elin - Thanks for your tips, but there's no backend display for what I want to do. Essentially I want to combine two display options into one (Showing all categories.. and then showing all contacts within each category underneath it in an unordered list). The issue seems to be that both files for category and child, use the same `$item->name` format

Comment: Oh I thought you meant for the front end. Can't you just get what you want by sorting the names by category? I mean the name of the category won't be on top but the contacts will be in that order.  The back end displays are designed for maximum flexibility (so you can sort and display by many different variables). From what you are saying you would want to limit it to display sorted by category?   You could so something like check the sort name and if it is categor yy add a header row.

Comment: Sorry, I do mean for the frontend, but I was referring to the options in the backend. Basically, I want to be able to show all contact categories on a page, and to show all contacts within their respective categories underneath the category title in a list form.

Comment: @Elin - So, Do you know any way I can reference the child contacts from the same PHP file that references the categories? Obviously just using child, will use any child categories, and not the contacts themselves.

Comment: I didn't check but I'm almost certain they are returned in the query results so you should be able to do that in a layout over ride by adding the echos.  I have always though that something like that would be a really good addition. On the other hand you can (I think) select multiple categories in the category list and arrange the display that way.

Comment: Well, yeah that's what I was trying to do in my question.. but I can't see anywhere to reference the contacts rather than the categories. And I'm pretty sure you've got the option to only select a single contact category to display, or ALL categories. So no luck as of yet. At the moment, I'm resorting to creating a PHP file with a list how I want it, and just including it in a single contact view.

Answer (score 0):

For `Category view` in file `default_children.php` after tag `<li...` add code:

```
    <?php

    // Get Category Model data
    $categoryModel = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Category', 'ContactModel', array('ignore_request' => true));

    $categoryModel->setState('category.id', $child->id);
    $categoryModel->setState('list.ordering', 'a.name');
    $categoryModel->setState('list.direction', 'asc');
    $categoryModel->setState('filter.published', 1);

    $contacts = $categoryModel->getItems();

    ?>
```

For `Custom Fields` add this after previus code:

```
    JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php');
    foreach($contacts as $contactItem) {
        $currentContFields[] = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_contact.contact', $contactItem, true);
}
```